How exactly are results being passed among processes via the pipes?
So Unix follows a uniform approach to I/O that allows programs to connect via pipes. I also know that to do that it uses file descriptors. But I heard someone saying that pipes allow attaching the stdout of one process to the stdin of another process with a small in-memory buffer and without writing the entire intermediate data stream to disk and this got me confused.

Lets say we have something like
cat foo.log | awk '{print $3}' | sort | uniq 


Lets assume that foo.log is a huge file, much bigger than would fit in RAM.

My question is: when we do that sort | uniq I originally thought that sort writes the entire sorted result to a file and pass the file descriptor of that file to uniq, but then hearing that comment (and also the fact that this approach would mean there is a temp left over file in HD), it seems that it passes the result via some intermediate in-memory buffer? Does that mean that the | part somehow invokes some other OS utility to read/pass data among processes?
How exactly does that work under the hood in Linux?

Do HOW LINUX PIPES WORK UNDER THE HOOD or the pipe.c source file in the Linux Kernel help?

sort is a bit special as it can use temporary files when the file doesn't fit in RAM, but it'll still copy the sorted records to its stdout eventually

What you might be missing is that Shell starts all four of those processes so they run simultaneously. As well as transferring data between the processes, Kernel regulates their scheduling so that readers wait for (some) data to be present, and writers wait for their (excess) output to be consumed.

@Paul_Pedant: That is helpful. I wasn't aware of that. I thought it executes the pipeline serially.

This question is similar to: In what order do piped commands run?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica': The order of how the commands run is not my question. My question is if programs produce a full output and pass a file descriptor to the next process or their output is chunked by some  OS component to be passed to the next program.

@smith  Every pipe comes with a hidden buffer (usually 64KB) for which the sender has a write fd and the Reader has a read fd. Huge buffers or disk store is not used. As all processes run (when they are not temporarily blocked by the buffering), the pipeline can run the processes in parallel to optimise use of multiple CPUs.

@Paul_Pedant: So there is some processing going on across the entire pipeline in parallel?

@smith  All the processes in the pipeline are eligible for scheduling unless they (a) have nothing to read, or (b) have no space to write, with their respective pipes. If there is no CPU available at that time (due to processing by any other processes, not just your pipeline) they will wait their turn for scheduling. So they are capable of simultaneous processing, but subject to other constraints.

Pipes are just a special sort of file descriptor which are created in pairs: one for the reading side, one for the writing side. The OS makes anything written to the write side available to be read on the read side.
In a pipeline like sort | uniq, the shell creates the pipe and the two fds, and arranges for the child processes to be started so that the stdout of the left-hand program (sort) is connected to the stdin of the right-hand program (uniq).
The programs themselves don't really care what sort of file descriptors they have, they just read from the stdin fd and write to the stdout fd in the same way regardless of if they have an fd pointing to a regular or an fd pointing to a pipe. Or one connected to terminal, which you get by default for anything producing output on an interactive session. File descriptors are identified through numbers, and stdin (0), stdout (1) and stderr (2) are just fds with well-known numbers and well-established conventions of use.
Under the hood, pipes of course work by memory buffers, but that's internal to the OS, not something the userland program needs to implement. IIRC the pipe buffer in the kernel is something like 64 kB in Linux, so larger data sets will not be kept in kernel memory in full. If the pipe is written faster than data is read off, the writer will block until enough data is read for the rest to fit in the buffer. And yes, the shell starts all programs in the pipeline in one go, so they run concurrently. (Passing fds from one process to another is actually also a thing, but it's a bit obscure and not something used here.)
Though sort in particular needs to read all of its input before it can produce any output, so it will need potentially a large buffer space internally, either in memory or using temporary files. But many other utilities can do their work while streaming through the file, often looking at just one line at a time, like your awk '{print $3}' there.

So the output of sort is controlled by the rate that uniq consumes data? Its not the case that sort finishes completely and then  uniq is forked by the shell?

@smith, yeah, pretty much. I think the pipe buffer within the kernel is something like 64 kB in Linux, so if sort here tries to write more than that in one go, it'll block until uniq gets around to reading it all (or at least enough so that the rest fits in the kernel buffer). And yes, the shell starts all programs in the pipeline in one go, so they run at the same time. So if you run something like grep | cut on a huge file, there's no need to keep all of it actively in memory at the same time, the data will just stream through both programs.

Saying that pipes are "a special sort of file descriptor" is IMO too big of a shortcut. A pipe is an IPC mechanism and kernel structure that looks like a real-life pipe with two ends and a limited storage capacity. When instantiated with the pipe() system call (as opposed to opening a named pipe for instance),  you do get two file descriptors (which are just indexes in the process' list of open files), one for each end.

Typically, when the amount of data becomes too big sort flushes intermediary sorted input to temp files, and it merges those temp files (which only need to store one line of input for each file in memory) in the end. That's how the original sort implementations did it in the 70s and how most still do (though some allow you to compress the temp files or adjust the limit above which sort will use temp files).
